# VMWare distributed switch, VMs from different hosts cannot ping one another

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, switch, vmware-vcenter

I am using ESXi 5.1 in the hosts, I have setup a distributed switch with corresponding uplink and port groups. When migrating to distributed switch, it seems that VMs from the same host can ping one another, but pinging VMs on different hosts fail.

I have used the default settings on creation of the uplink and port groups, it seems very strange and I cannot find anything useful on the internet.

Distributed switch topology figure shows all VMs on the same port group having green colors as well as the uplinks, it seems perfectly normal but VMs from different hosts cannot ping.

Any ideas? Anyone with similar problem?

[image]

Comment: Is the physical network good?  All the physical ports share the same VLANs, etc?

Comment: Yes it seems ok. And there are no vlans.

Comment: Just to get this clear: Everything worked on non-distributed virtual switches and then you migrated everything to a distributed virtual switch and it stopped working? Same configuration on the port groups, same uplinks, no changes in the network? Can you migrate back to local switches (at the moment, it doesn't work anyway) and show us the configuration that works?

Comment: I could not ping VMs from different hosts before trying distributed virtual switches. So "everything worked" is not true, it was just normal the VMs could ping one another as parts of the same switch in the same host. The configuration was exactly the same, apart from the port group that was assigned to network interfaces.

Comment: On the second host itselft if you issue ping does it work ?

Comment: Ping works when I ping ESXi host to ESXi host and between VMs in the same ESXi host. But ping between VMs in different hosts does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I understand your network setup. In your management port group you work with a VLAN trunk range of 0-4094. This implies you're working with tagged VLANs on your uplinks, see [Edit the VLAN Policy on a Distributed Port Group in the vSphere Web Client](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-D5960C77-0D19-4669-A00C-B05D58A422F8.html).

On the other hand, the port group that gives you trouble works untagged. To the best of my knowledge, switches allow you to work with tagged *or* untagged VLANs, you can't mix them.

Did this work on your local virtual switches, i.e. were you able to mix the untagged port group and the VLAN trunking port group there without any problems?

*edit:* Try to use `VLAN` or `VLAN Trunking` on the port group that's not working at the moment.

*edit2:* If you use specific VLANs (not VLAN Trunking, I don't know if this works) on your port groups, you can make use of [Network Health Check](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/12/vsphere-5-1-vds-new-features-network-health-check.html) (KB article: [Enabling vSphere Distributed Switch health check in the vSphere Web Client](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2032878)) to troubleshoot your problems.

Comment: ok thanks, this is not the problem. I have made everything untagged and still no luck. I tried also creating a new vds with only one port group , either tagged or untagged didnot work.

Comment: I saw in a blog that for them they had to change the "teaming and failover load balancing" to "route based on IP hash" with the corresponding LACP changes , but still no luck.. its very strange..

Comment: Your hosts only have one uplink so the load balancing policy shouldn't matter- all network traffic will go through this one uplink. Since you're talking about LACP changes: Do you use LACP? Can the VMs in vIMS02_IO ping each other across hosts?

Comment: No, this is what I want to solve. VMs cannot ping each other across hosts. When they are in the same host they can ping.

Comment: Sorry, I'm running out of ideas. I think it's time for you to open a support request with VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Though [this](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.troubleshooting.doc%2FGUID-5324A0E4-AA7B-40CC-A975-D45328B5C434.html) post is for Esxi 5.5, you may check whether this solves your issue.

You may also check [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/VMWare/Q_27992058.html).

Comment: Thanks but the first one has already been checked, the uplinks are OK and there is connectivity between different ESXi hosts, also no VLANs are used. The second one tried also no luck

Comment: Are all you hosts of the same version?

Answer (score -2):

i dont know if you have already solved that but thats a bug in some part of the cisco ucs firmware. should be fixed with the newest version if u want i can send u the link

Comment: If you have the link (and one for an errata), why don't you just post it, together with a short summary of the problem?

Comment: I'm currently down voting this answer because of the lack of documentation / specifics. However if this ends up being the solution, I'll gladly up vote.